# how to receive notifications of navigation through Google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, notifications

i face some problem in my project of android...My application take current position of user and final destination position.than calculate the shortest path and highlight it on Google map...my problem is how i receive notification message when user follow that highlighted path that after let suppose 10meter  user take right turn or left turn...?ThankXx

Answer (score 1):

Nor entirely sure what you mean, but do you want to receive the notifications from the Google Maps app? For example, the 'Turn left here' , 'In 200 meters, take the first exit at the roundabout', take a look at the accessibility service in Android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

It can read notifications that are up in the notification bar. You can get it to trigger every time the Navigation notification updates.